# Dropdownlist value changes on page refresh

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

`I have a Gridview with a checkbox.The Grid is loaded based on values of two dropdownlist. The values in a dropdownlist is loaded based on web services.

Now my problem is when the checkbox is selected the page is refreshed and the values in dropdownlist will be set to default.That is, in any case when the page is refreshed the dropdownlists value is set to default. Only the dropdownlists value is changed,other fields value remains the same.I tried using updatepanel but it didn't work.

Any help will be really appreciated.

```
                                <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Prov" CssClass="txtboxAll" Width="260px" 
    runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown1" runat="server"
    Category="facil" TargetControlID="ddl_Prov" PromptText="[SelectGroup]"
    LoadingText="Loading  Group..." ServicePath="~/Services/eservice.asmx"
    ServiceMethod="GetDropDownProgroup"></asp:CascadingDropDown>
    </td>
    <td>

   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Pro" CssClass="txtboxAll" Width="260px"
   runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdd_fa" runat="server" Category="facility"  
   ParentControlID="ddl_Prov"  TargetControlID="ddl_Pro" 
   PromptText="[Select Pr]" LoadingText="Loading Provider..."
  ServicePath="~/Services/Freservice.asmx" 
  ServiceMethod="GetDropDownFacilitybyGr">
  </asp:CascadingDropDown> 
       </td>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" 
            UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="grd_ViewPayments" DataKeyNames="IN077_01" 
              runat="server" Width="100%"  
             DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="true" 
              showfooter="true" PageSize="20" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="grd_ViewPayments_SelectedIndexChanged" 
              OnRowDataBound="grd_ViewPayments_RowDataBound">
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D8E4F2" />
                            <HeaderStyle cssclass="Header" />
                 <FooterStyle cssclass="Header" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                             <RowStyle cssclass="rowsgrd" />
                            <HeaderStyle cssclass="Header" />
                            <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="3" position="Bottom" />  
                            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#36b0b6" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#E1E1E1" />

                <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="SlNo." 
                                   ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="30px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="3%" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="pid" HeaderText="VID" 
                        SortExpression="pid" >
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150px" />
                                                                    </asp:BoundField>

                   <asp:BoundField DataField="pname"  HeaderText="Pr Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                       SortExpression="pname">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150px" />
                                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        SortExpression="amount" >
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        SortExpression="date" >
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                     <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="3%">
                                     <HeaderTemplate>
                                     <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_All" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="chk_All_CheckedChanged"  />
                                     </HeaderTemplate>
                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_select" OnCheckedChanged="chk_select_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"  />
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="3%" />
                                     </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NCPConnectionString %>"                                                
                       SelectCommand="SPPS_1" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                       <SelectParameters>
                           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddl_Prov" DefaultValue="All" 
                               Name="pro1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddl_Pro" DefaultValue="All" 
                               Name="pr" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                       </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>


            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="but_search" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="grd_ViewPayments" />

        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: So, on page refresh what do you want the value of the two drop downs to be? Do you want them to be their default values?

Comment: No I just want the selected value

Comment: You mean what was previously selected should be maintained. Also, which checkbox are you clicking when your page refreshes?

Comment: why are you using web service to load dropdown. why not load directly from code behind?

Comment: Yes the previously selected value should be maintained. chk_All will be clicked . .

Comment: Check my answer and try it. There could be some more issues with your UpdatePanel, but first try the suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Why do you have the first cascading drop down in UpdatePanel? And, also why the second cascading drop down is in an UpdatePanel? They don't need to be in UpdatePanel, unless you are updating some other elements on your page when their selected index is changed.

Comment: Cascading drop downs already make an ajax request by themselves without any UpdatePanel, so why do you put them in UpdatePanel?

Comment: You have used UpdatePanels in the wrong way and that is causing this issue.

Comment: The values in the dropdownlist is loaded based on a webservice.

Comment: so there is no need of updatepanels ???

Comment: Cascading dropdowns are part of `ajaxcontroltoolkit` and they make an ajax request without any update panel. The `ajaxcontroltoolkit` will automatically call the web service for you using an ajax request.

Comment: But you can still have some controls like your gridview or button in the UpdatePanel if they need to make an ajax request, since they don't make an ajax request by default.

Comment: Even if the updatepanel is removed ,still the problem exists. Dropdownlist value is not maintained.

Comment: Can you paste your code after removal of update panels for cascading drop downs?

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: Can you run your page and see what's happening? did you set EnableEventValidation="false"?

Comment: also, try opening your page in a private window if browser caching is creating your issue.

Comment: Found out the mistake .It was because I have given <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="grd_ViewPayments" /> so the page is postback and the dropdownlists values are loaded again and lose its selected value.

Comment: @Sunil Thank you very much for our time and considertion . Was stuck with this for hours .Thank you for your guidance too. Since I was new to c# I couldn't find out this simple error.Thanks once again.